# create a spark dataframe from a nested json file in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, nested, apache-spark-sql

I have a json file that looks like this

```
{
"group" : {},
"lang" : [ 
    [ 1, "scala", "functional" ], 
    [ 2, "java","object" ], 
    [ 3, "py","interpreted" ]
]
}
```

I tried to create a dataframe using

```
val path = "some/path/to/jsonFile.json"
val df = sqlContext.read.json(path)
df.show()
```

when I run this I get

```
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_corrupt_record: string]
```

How do we create a df based on contents of "lang" key? I do not care about group{} all I need is, pull data out of "lang" and apply case class like this

```
case class ProgLang (id: Int, lang: String, type: String )
```

I have read this post [Reading JSON with Apache Spark - `corrupt_record`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38895057/reading-json-with-apache-spark-corrupt-record) and understand that each record needs to be on a newline but in my case I cannot change the file structure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `json` format is wrong. The the `json` api of `sqlContext` is reading it as corrupt record. Correct form is

```
{"group":{},"lang":[[1,"scala","functional"],[2,"java","object"],[3,"py","interpreted"]]}
```

and supposing you have it in a file ("/home/test.json"), then you can use following method to get the `dataframe` you want

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import sqlContext.implicits._

val df = sqlContext.read.json("/home/test.json")

val df2 = df.withColumn("lang", explode($"lang"))
    .withColumn("id", $"lang"(0))
    .withColumn("langs", $"lang"(1))
    .withColumn("type", $"lang"(2))
    .drop("lang")
    .withColumnRenamed("langs", "lang")
    .show(false)
```

You should have

```
+---+-----+-----------+
|id |lang |type       |
+---+-----+-----------+
|1  |scala|functional |
|2  |java |object     |
|3  |py   |interpreted|
+---+-----+-----------+
```

**Updated**

If you don't want to change your input json format as mentioned in your comment below, you can use `wholeTextFiles` to read the `json` file and `parse` it as below

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val readJSON = sc.wholeTextFiles("/home/test.json")
  .map(x => x._2)
  .map(data => data.replaceAll("\n", ""))

val df = sqlContext.read.json(readJSON)

val df2 = df.withColumn("lang", explode($"lang"))
  .withColumn("id", $"lang"(0).cast(IntegerType))
  .withColumn("langs", $"lang"(1))
  .withColumn("type", $"lang"(2))
  .drop("lang")
  .withColumnRenamed("langs", "lang")

df2.show(false)
df2.printSchema
```

It should give you `dataframe` as above and `schema` as

```
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- lang: string (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Ramesh, I should have been more clear, I cannot change my json file format and it contains just a single json doc i.e. data shared earlier and it has newlines whereas in your case its all in a single line.

Comment: is it in the same format as you pasted in your question? how another record is added in that format then?

Comment: yes, format remains same, within .json file it is the "lang" : [ 4, "ruby","interpreted" ] that gets new data

Comment: I think I am getting closer, I now have a df with group and lang schema

root
 |-- lang: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

here's the code
`val readJSON = sc.wholeTextFiles("'home/data.json").map(x => 
  x._2).map(data => data.replaceAll("""[\n]+""", " "))
  val df = sqlContext.read.json(readJSON)
     df.printSchema`

Comment: yeah I was thinking to use wholeTextFiles as well. You got it right . After that you can just use my solution above. :) the part of creating df2 :)

Comment: I have updated my answer :) please check

Answer (score 2):

[As of Spark 2.2](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20980) you can use `multiLine` option to deal with the case of multi-line JSONs.

```
scala> spark.read.option("multiLine", true).json("jsonFile.json").printSchema
root
 |-- lang: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Before Spark 2.2 see [How to access sub-entities in JSON file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44814926/1305344) or [Read multiline JSON in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38545850/1305344).